# Synchronize databases in different remote sources to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, json, database, postgresql

I have several applications in different geographic locations that work offline because there is no internet access in those places. All applications store the same type of information, and each one stores the information in its own local database.

The problem is that every given time I need to replicate the information from all the local databases to a single database. I have thought about generating a JSON file for each of the applications and then loading it somewhere with Internet access and using a Web service to read the file and store the information.

I don't know if this is the best approach since the files could contain thousands of records and the information is sensitive. I wonder if there is a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about your application so I cannot see if there could be some serious conflicts on IDs, unique indexes or something similar.

But technically you can simplify combining of data from all local databases into the central one by using partitions. Partitions act as completely separate tables with independent indexes so even with the same IDs you will not have problems to import data into partitions. And thanks to inheritance from one main parent table you will be able to select in simple way from all of them.

The same solution with partitions (i.e. separate partition suffix for each local database) you can use for all tables so you do not need to worry about things like multimaster replication etc. It will require some work on import part but it will save you many problems with some "more sophisticated" solution.

The way how you transport data from local databases is not so important from the database point of view. If you like JSON why not. But PostgreSQL so fat does not have native support for JSON export/import - so you have to write your own functions. On the other hand dump/restore or CSV export/import work natively very well in PostgreSQL.